# What is the best approuch to create a single page application React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, single-page-application, react-router-dom

Whether to use `react-router-dom` for page routing or simply manage components in the same screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject some components in React in other framework or web page but if you build a ReactJS application, it's basically a single page application.

In your application you will have to use a router like:

- React router : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router
- React redux router : https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

There are many other, but those are good for begun.

In a second hand, you will have to manage some components by yourself for example, when you create a new route for display the profile of a user, you will have some components to display or not if the users put all his personal information or not.

Well the profile component is manage by the router and each users information line could be manage by smaller components.